# using javascript in included views in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

What is the best practice for using or not using javascript in a partial view (a helper jsp included by parent jsp)?

In general, I want to use partial views for listing results in a parent view and there should be some listeners on items of result list, so I want to bind js events like click on these items created by partial view.

What are advantages/disadvantages of binding these listeners on included jsp or parent jsp?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on ! What work you want to do on your listeners ? If you want to do works like showing a popup or ui elements , this is may be good , but you should not do your business logic in js . In general the js itself has some disadvantage like security issues and  rendering varies(Different layout engines may render Javascript differently resulting in inconsistency in terms of functionality and interface). So I prefer you use js if you really need it !